# Display object list with a parameter on Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a find query that returns me a list of objects:

```
{
    "_id": "5fb94fda487b9348c4291450",
    "name": [
        {
            "NewConfirmed": 642686,
            "TotalConfirmed": 49315431,
            "NewDeaths": 9555,
            "TotalDeaths": 1242785,
            "NewRecovered": 288131,
            "TotalRecovered": 32473892
        },
        {
            "NewConfirmed": 116262,
            "TotalConfirmed": 6014461,
            "NewDeaths": 4640,
            "TotalDeaths": 371913,
            "NewRecovered": 77575,
            "TotalRecovered": 2492884
        },
        {
    ...
```

Its all fine but I'm trying to make a new query with a status parameter with the value `NewConfirmed` or `TotalConfirmed` or `NewDeaths` to display only that specific field. So the endpoints would look like `/something/status/:status`.

I already tried an aggregation with filter and a simple find but still havent figured nothing out.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: For example, to have a select with multiple values where depending on the string value that i pass "NewConfirmed, NewDeath, etc" I get the respetive specific values

Comment: You want to return the object with all subdocument into the array, but only with the field specified by parameter?

Comment: Its easy to understand:
My endpoint is potatoes/${status}
Status = "NewConfirmed"

return "NewConfirmed": 642686,

Comment: So you want ONLY the first value into the array. That's not easy at all if you not specify it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a query with this estructure:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    /**Your match object*/
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "YourStatus": {
        "$first": "$name.YourStatus"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AGJ4e654OgE).

Using `mongoose` you need to create the object query in this way:

```js
var query = {}
query[status] = {"$first": "$name."+status}
```

And do the `mongoose` query replacing the object by `query` object.

```js
var aggregate = await model.aggregate([
  {
    //Your $match stage here
  },
  {
    "$project": query
  }
])
```

Also, I've tested in local but my mongo version (I think) doesn't recognize `$first` so I've used `$arrayElemAt`. According to [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/) is the same as `$first`.

```js
var status = "NewConfirmed"
var query = {}
query[status] = { $arrayElemAt: ["$name."+status, 0]}
```

Also you can add `_id: 0` into `$project` aggregate to not return this field.

```js
var query = {_id:0} //Here add _id: 0 to project object
query[status] = { $arrayElemAt: ["$name."+status, 0]}  //And the rest of the stage
```